# Can I connect my website to my personal computer SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I already have an website on godaddy, So can I connect SQL Server database (Database is in my home PC) from website which is already launched in godaddy. I did my website using Asp.net.

If can, what are all the things I should give importance?

**Note:**
My database is not huge.

Please help me.

Comment: If your home pc is a server, and proper ports are opened via your ISP.  The database can be exposed to the web, and your website could connect to it.

Comment: I would configure a specific user account in sql-server that only has access to the DB schema that are used in the web site

Comment: Yes you can connect to your local sql server database. Check this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/60680/how-to-connect-to-a-local-sql-server

Comment: Surely it would be easier to use the SQL Server databases provided by godaddy

Comment: @Simon I want to test it before I do launch. So that I just want to do some testing. That's y

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking yes you can, should you..unless your home computer is a server, no.  You would have to ensure that you have a static IP address and allow 1433 through your firewall.  honestly its not that costly to get a cloud sqlserver and hook to that, discountasp.net has really good service.

Comment: 1433 is Port number from firewall?

Comment: Yes 1433 is the default sql port, you can change it through the configuration tool..https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access

Comment: Are you using express or full blown sql?

Comment: I am using sql express

Comment: Make sure when you point to the IP that you have the instance name correct, if  when you installed the sql server you named the instance anything but "Mssqlserver" you will need to refer it it as <IpAddress>\<InstanceName>  if you used the default named instance during the setup you would refer to it as <IpAddress>\SqlExpress

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can do it. I assume you want to know how to connect to it.

1. Set a static IP for you computer ex: 192.168.1.105 (make sure you are on the same subnet as your default gateway.
2. Open the firewall for your sql server.
3. Go into router settings and do port forwarding to the static IP (from step 1) and the port of your SQL server ex: 1433
4. Connect your website to the database using public IP (google what is my ip) 
   example: 123.123.123.12:1433

This should work.